# Categorical Bar Graph 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning visualisation in R and have been facing some issues trying to make a categorical bar graph from data that I extracted from a .xlsx file in R.

The input had numerous columns and I created a dataframe with the two columns i needed for the graph. When i run the following in R, I get the error

```
"Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?"
```

This is my script:

```
df<-read_excel("C:\\..\\excel.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1")
unique_df<-unique(mis[c("Vegetables", "Fruits")])

ggplot(data = unique_df, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(unique_df["Vegetables"]),
y = unique_df["Fruits"])) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
labs(x = "Vegetables", y="Fruits", title="Number of Codes", subtitle="Vegetables wise number of fruits")
```

This is similar to the dataframe (unique_df) that I need to make the visualisation from:

```
x             y
Red           Mango
Red           Apple
Red           Banana
Blue          Mango
Blue          Banana
Blue          Banana
Blue          Apple
Yellow        Pineapple
Green         Mango
Yellow        Pineapple
Yellow        Pineapple
Green         Apple
```

Output of `str(unique_df)`

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   219 obs. of  2 variables:
x: chr "Red" "Red" "Red" "Blue" "Blue"...
y: chr "Mango" "Apple" "Banana" "Mango"...
```

Comment: Inside `aes` you typically only want unquoted variable names, not subsetting. For the provided data, maybe `ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = y)) + geom_bar()`

Comment: @alistaire
if i don't subset (i.e. use double quotes) then i get the error `"Error: unexpected symbol in "ggplot(data =..."`

Output of "colnames(unique_df) is 

`[1] "Vegetables" "Fruits"`

Comment: You need to make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could i be facing issue with making a count of "Fruits" "Vegetable" wise because of text type column names? Output of `colname(unique_df)` is `[1] "Vegetables" "Fruits"`

Comment: No, names don't have types in R. You need to make your example reproducible. If answerers can't cause the same error, this question is not answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume df -- data frame and "a" and "b are columns.
Try below codes--and image of plot attached.
`ggplot(data = df,aes(x=df$a,fill=df$b))+geom_bar()`
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! this is exactly what i was looking for and it resolved my problem.

Comment: @PranavSeth please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` subsetting in `aes`; sooner or later it will cause really wacky bugs. Use the bare variable name instead: `aes(x = a, fill = b)`.